# Remove menu items from notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I recently updated my notepad++ (was using a very old one), but now I get this ton of menu items which clutter my UI. Things like Zen Coding, Grep, CSS Lint, JSHint and a dozen more. How do I get rid of those?

Comment: Hi @helfdane, I think this answer will help you to solve your problem https://superuser.com/questions/1176224/customize-menu-bar-in-notepad

Comment: Try running Notepad++ with the `-noPlugins` command line option and see whether the unwanted menu items disappear. If they do then remove any plugins that insert the unwanted menu items.

Comment: @AdrianHHH Tried it, but apparently those extra menu items are not from plugins. Thanx for your reply tho!

Comment: @Surenthar Pitchai Thanks for the link, but I was hoping it didn't involve hacking the executable.

Comment: Where in the UI are these unwanted items? Do they appear in any of the [configuration files](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Configuration_Files).

Comment: They come after the Window-item. They apparently don't come from configuration, but seem to be baked into the executable.

Answer (score 1):

All theese menus are added by the [jN Notepad++ Plugin](https://github.com/sieukrem/jn-npp-plugin/wiki).

The plugin lready has a feature request "[Put all menus under one main menu entry in the menu bar](https://github.com/sieukrem/jn-npp-plugin/issues/11)".
At first the author [objected](https://github.com/sieukrem/jn-npp-plugin/issues/11#issuecomment-82191131):

> I don't like that all plugins are collected together under "Plugins" menu item. It was a restriction of N++ I broke.

Then he said that the complaints [got him thinking](https://github.com/sieukrem/jn-npp-plugin/issues/11#issuecomment-82191134). But all this happened back in 2015... ;)

So you can remove this plugin or manualy edit all js files in its `include` directory to place all these menus in the one common menu item.